# Any Rhythmbox plugin for grooveshark out there?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, grooveshark

I can't find a plugin to listen GS on RB for Ubuntu. I currently run 10.04.

Comment: Related Ubuntu Forums thread [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1559779).

Answer (score 2):

There is none. Grooveshark is mainly driven by ads. Using it from somewhere other than their website won't give them any revenue.

Comment: again, if you buy a subscription, there're no more ads

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=http://www.taringa.net/posts/linux/12016068/Plugin-Grooveshark-para-Rhythmbox.html&ei=MPLDTpuxJIS3twfvhMGtDQ&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CHUQ7gEwCA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Drhythmbox%2Bplugin%2Bgrooveshark%26hl%3Den%26prmd%3Dimvnsfd) (note: [original in Spanish](http://usemoslinux.blogspot.com/2011/08/plugin-grooveshark-para-rhythmbox.html)):

1. Download the "Grooveshark Music" plugin here:  [Grooveshark_ES2.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10107072/Grooveshark_ES2.zip).
2. Extract the zip folder into `/home/<your username>/.gnome2/rhythmbox/plugins/`.
3. In Rhythmbox, go to **Edit > Plugins** and enable the "Grooveshark Music" plugin.

The linked blog post includes a YouTube video of the plugin in use.

**WARNING:** *I have not tried this solution, and I cannot verify the usefulness or safety of using the download. The author of the blog post noted that this is something they wrote and it is to be considered "beta" software, so keep this in mind before proceeding.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try gsharkdown, it is a separate player allows you to play and download from grooveshark. I installed it via ppa, it worked once, but then it didnt after that could have been just me. But that is another option.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/gsharkdown

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gsharkdown
```